# Complex Analysis with Mathematica, Simplify, Absolute value

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I don't manage to make Mathematica understand that x*Conjugate[x]=Abs[x]^2.

For example, let's assume you have :

```
x*Conjugate[x]^3
```

How do you make Mathematica simplify it into :

```
Abs[x]^2*Conjugate[x]^2
```

?

Comment: By most metrics the second expression is "less simple" than the second. (Hence the first expression would be prefered by `Simplify`, even if Mathematica was considering the proper transformations)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
expr = x*Conjugate[x]^3;

Simplify[expr /. x -> r*Exp[I*t], {r > 0, t > 0}] /. 
  t :> I*Log[Conjugate[x]/r] /. r -> Abs[x]

(*   Abs[x]^2 Conjugate[x]^2 *)
```

Have fun!